# Create custom search query web parts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I have built some custom search query web parts and want to make them more dynamic.

**For example,** I would like them to be a webpart that users can add and point to a list/document library and choose what columns they want to display.

Looking for advice on best way to achieve this? Any links etc. Don't know c# but is that my only option?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Content Query web part?

It can display contents based on your configuration:
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929

If you want to display contents dynamically, you need to create a custom web part, which is similar as CQWP. You need to use Visual Studio to create a custom web part:http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/24/how-to-create-a-custom-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/